# How to disable activiti auto deployment on Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activiti, bpmn

I have a Spring Boot project where I used `activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic 5.22` dependency.

But whenever I am running the Spring Boot app the processes in `src/main/resources/processes` will always get deploy if it has been changed and I don't want it to deploy.

How can I disable auto deploy on Spring Boot?

Comment: not sure but I think you should be using some annotations or calls to these processes inside your Controllers or Components. Take a look here https://www.activiti.org/userguide/index.html . See if it helps!

Comment: Possibly it is not related to spring-boot. Most of IDEs has auto deploy feature. You may investigate your ide's settings to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following properties to your application.properties file in your spring boot application (examples below):

```
spring.activiti.checkProcessDefinitions = true
spring.activiti.processDefinitionLocationPrefix = classpath:/processes/
spring.activiti.processDefinitionLocationSuffixes = *.bpmn20.xml, *.bpmn
```

Cheers,
Greg

Comment: Work like a charm!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using Activity 6.0 together with Spring Boot, I think it's the `spring.activiti.checkProcessDefinitions` property that controls the autodeployment.